# Induction step completion

Tags: induction

I am confused how to go about the inductive step of the this given problem..

For all natural numbers $n, 2+4+6+....+2n =(n^2+n)$

I got the base case but now I am confused. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
Proof: We proceed by induction.
          Base case: Set n = 1. Then 2 = (1)^2 + 1. Thus the 
          claim holds when n = 1.

       Inductive step: Let n>=1 be given.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the (n+1)th term of the series on both sides of $P(n)$ : 
[**Here i have assumed P(n) to be the the given proposition**]$$2+4+6+...+2n+2(n+1)=n^2+n+2(n+1)$$

RHS: $n^2+n+2(n+1)=(n+1)^2+(n+1)$  [You may check that!]
So as per induction hypothesis your proposition is true for $n+1$, ie $P(n+1)$ is true holding $P(n)$ to be true.That proves your proposition to be true for all natural numbers as per the standard induction hypothesis.

Comment: Okay so I understand why you added 2(n+1) to each side but how does that prove that it's true?

Comment: Just assume the entire proposition in the question to be$P(n)$ and then just plug in n+1 there, you get $P(n+1)$ which is actually what i have deduced above. We actually had assumed $P(n)$ to be true and then holding that we proved $P(n+1)$ to be true. That is what we wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The inductive step starts:

> Let $n\geq 1$ be given such that
>   $$
>     2 + 4 + 6 + \dots + 2n = n^2 + n
> $$
>   We wish to show that
>   $$
>     2 + 4 + 6 + \dots + 2n + 2(n+1) = (n+1)^2 + (n+1)
> $$

Now you try to use the first equation to prove the second.  Can you do that?

---

OP asks about the appearance of $2n$ in the second equation.  If you infer the pattern from the $\cdots$, then
$$
    2 + 4 + 6 + \dots + 2(n+1) = 2 + 4 + 6 + \dots + 2n + 2(n+1)
$$
In both cases, you double all the numbers between $1$ and $n+1$, and add up those doubles.  I just decided to explicitly write not only the *last* term in the series, but also the *next-to-last* term.

Why would I do that?  It emphasizes that the left-hand side of the second equation is the same as the left-hand side of the first equation, with an additional term added on: $2(n+1)$.  That is a hint for how to show the second equation is satisfied.

Comment: Why did you keep the 2n and then add the 2(n+1)? Shouldn't the 2n have been just change to 2(n+1)?

Comment: @MirrandaRyan Good question.  See edit.

Comment: @amWhy I think OP is confused about what is elided by the $\cdots$ in a series.  In some sense both are valid expressions.